# Formal languages - exercise

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to solve this exercise: given $L=\left\{a^kb^k|k>0\right\}$
determine $L^2$ and $L^3$.

So I'm able to solve this kind of exercise if k is given into a defined range but I'm really struggling to solve this exercise.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: There's no Kleene star here. Why do you mention it? Anyway $L^2$ is just the concatenation $L\cdot L$, so apply the concatenation definition, simplify it a bit, and you should have your answer.

Comment: @chi Yes, I've corrected the title. I know that I need to concatenate but I can't determine the elements because k can be any positive value. I've tried another excercise in which k ranged from 0 to 2 so the elements were determinable.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly enumerate an infinite language to solve this -- that would be impossible. You can write the answer using set notation like $\{ a^n b^m a^i b^j c^k | n+m>k+i+j \}$ to express an infinite language.

Comment: Maybe, you could start with an easier exercise, first. How would express the concatenation $\{a^n | n>0\} \cdot \{b^n | n>0\}$, for instance ? Surely, it is $a^*b^*$, but can you write that in set notation without exploiting Kleene stars?

Comment: I think you mean that the concatenation result is $a^nb^n$ but I can't understand how that can help. Forgive me but the professor hasn't solved many exercises like this one.

Comment: I've tried to solve it with this: $L^2=\left\{a^nb^nab|n>0\right\}$ But I'm not sure that it's a good solution

Comment: Regarding my example: note that $\{a^nb^n | n>0\}$ is not $a^*b^*$, since the former can not contain the string $aaabb$ -- we need to allow different n's. A proper answer could be $\{a^nb^m | n>0, m>0 \}$, which is equal to $a^*b^*$.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: $L^2$ is a precise definition of a language. There are infinitely many others. What does "determine" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider $L^2$.
As stated in the comments you can consider it as $L \cdot L$.

Think to it as the concatenation of two different languages.

$L_1 = \{a^{i}b^{i}\ | \ i > 0\}$ and 
$L_2 = \{a^{j}b^{j}\ | \ j > 0\}$.

$L_1 \cdot L_2 = \{ w_1\cdot w_2\  |\ w_1 \in L_1, \ w_2 \in L_2\}$

As set $L_1 = \{ab, aabb, aaabbb,...\}$, $L_2 = \{ab, aabb, aaabbb,...\}$

$\color{blue}{L_1} \cdot \color{red}{L_2} = \{ 
\color{blue}{ab}\color{red}{ab},\
\color{blue}{ab}\color{red}{aabb},\
\color{blue}{ab}\color{red}{aaaabbbb},\
\color{blue}{ab}\color{red}{aaaaabbbbb},\
\color{blue}{ab}\color{red}{aaaaaabbbbbb},...,
\color{blue}{aabb}\color{red}{ab},\
\color{blue}{aabb}\color{red}{aabb},...
\}$

Can you express $L^2$ with a compact notation?

Comment: Can it be: $L=\left\{a^nb^na^ib^i | n,i>0\right\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely $L^2$. Now I'm sure you can guess $L^3$.